# Resistance of armature circuit in DC machines

Tags: dc-motor

I was solving a numerical problem in DC machines. The given information is as follows:

- Armature current = 40 A
- No load EMF produced = 806.4 V
- Lap winding, so no of parallel paths = poles = 6
- No of armature coils = 240 of 2 turns each
- Resistance of one turn = 0.03 Ω

I had to find the terminal voltage at full load current = 40 A.

The given solution is:

- No of armature turns per path = 480/6 = 80
- Resistance of one path = 80*0.03 = 2.4 Ω
- Resistance of armature circuit = Resistance of one path/no of parallel paths = 2.4/6 = 0.4 Ω

This is the part where I have an issue:

I don't understand the reasoning behind the calculation of the resistance of the armature circuit.

Comment: What don't you understand?  I'm guessing the 80, which should be 240/2 = 120.

Answer (score 1):

The equation for the resistance of the armature circuit is essentially a shortcut equation for parallel resistors.

If there were 2 paths, the equivalent resistance of 2 parallel identical resistors is R_eq = R^2/(2R) = R/2. If we reuse this result in this scenario, we get R_eq = (R/2) || (R/2) || (R/2)

1/R_eq = 2/R + 2/R + 2/R = 6/R --> R_eq = R/6

Where R here is equal to the resistance of one path (in your case 2.4 Ω)

If you find this confusing, just calculate the armature resistance by using the regular parallel resistance formula.